# Silverlight Toolkit LinearAxis Minimum Interval

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-toolkit

I am using the silverlight toolkit and have a chart that houses a LineSeries with two linear axis.

I want the interval of a linear axis to remain at "auto" but do not want the interval to go below 1 as decimal values are irrelevant/confusing for the user.

Is there a way to set this in the code and/or XAML?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, just dont set the minimum and maximum on the axis and they should stay as auto

```
<charting:Chart.Resources>
    <charting:LinearAxis x:Key="yAxis" Orientation="Y" Interval="1" />
</charting:Chart.Resources>

<charting:LineSeries
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourDataSource}"
                DependentRangeAxis="{StaticResource yAxis}">
</charting:LineSeries>
```